# How to create Oracle event trigger that will log table creations

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I am trying to write a trigger that fires after user creates a new table, and logs the creation of table into an audit table.

I have the below starter code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER create_table_trigger
AFTER CREATE
ON SCHEMA
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO TABS_MODS (ID,ACTION) VALUES (1, 'CREATE TAB');
END;
```

TABS_MODS is a global temporary table like below:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TABS_MODS (
  id NUMBER,
  action  VARCHAR2(20)
) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

But on creating table I am not seeing anything in the TABS_MODS table.

Comment: Why are you even bothering with this?  Oracle already provides this capability as part of its AUDIT system.

Comment: @EdStevens is right. Oracle's AUDIT functionality is designed to do exactly what you're describing. Also, why a temporary table? The contents of temporary tables are only visible within the session that inserts the data. You can't query them from another session, and the data will not persist once the originating session ends. They are useless for auditing.

Answer (score 0):

Use Oracle's built-in auditing features to do this. Audit the "CREATE TABLE" and "CREATE ANY TABLE" privileges. You didn't specify which version of Oracle you're using, but you can start here and search for more version-specific examples if you need them: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/auditing.htm